# How to use sshfs to map linux server requiring double authentication?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, sshfs

I have problems using sshfs to map a linux server that requires double authentication.

The server is accessible via ssh in two steps:

1) ssh access with user and passwd

2) sudo user2 and passwd.

The user2 is not directly accessible by ssh from my site.

It's possible to access this server using sshfs?

Do you have information about an sshfs configuration to solve this problem by avoiding server changes that require administrative privileges?

Comment: I think the 2nd post here might work for you : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=107875

Comment: @Dexirian I'll try the tricks I found into the URL you indicated me and tell you the result. I am certainly not allowed to install software that requires administrative privileges and I am sure the sysadmin will not want to install bindfs.